# lists generated by a for loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a for loop. Each time it iterates, prints a list. But, some of the printed lists are the same. How can I understand how many different lists I have and what are the different lists? In other words, I just want to see the distinct lists and the number of them.

Thank you

Comment: Without your code, it will be difficult to help you. Likely, you want to use a `Table` instead of a `For` loop, and then use something like `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: Beware of using  `Print[ ]` for anything other than printing messages. You can prepare a list in a `For[ ]` loop, but it is much better to use `Table[ ]` or `Map[ ]`

Answer (score 2):

`DeleteDuplicates[ ]`

and

`Length[DeleteDuplicates[ ]]`

Comment: Thanks all. The commands work!

Comment: @A. Mpi:  So perhaps an *accept* or at least *up-vote* perhaps?